# How can I create a simple P2SH transaction in regtest?

Tags: bitcoind, p2sh, regtest

I'm running `bitcoind` in the regtest mode on my computer. I need at least one transaction that spends a P2SH output in my local blockchain. Is there a way to create a P2SH transaction using `bitcoin-cli`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes we could do that easily, first we launch bitcoin core on regtest `bitcoind -regtest -fallbackfee=0.0002 -daemon`

then we create and load a wallet

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest createwallet "my_wallet"
```

then we generate 100 blocks to get some coins `bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress 101 "$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress)"`

then we gonna need 3 new addresses for our 2-of-3 multisig address so lets create them

```
ADDR1=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress)
ADDR2=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress)
ADDR3=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress)
```

We get the public keys associated ( you might need `jq` here )

```
PUBKEY1=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getaddressinfo $ADDR1 | jq -r '.pubkey')
PUBKEY2=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getaddressinfo $ADDR2 | jq -r '.pubkey')
PUBKEY3=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getaddressinfo $ADDR3 | jq -r '.pubkey')
```

then we create our 2-of-3 multisig address `P2SH_MULTISIG=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest createmultisig 2 "[\"$PUBKEY1\",\"$PUBKEY2\",\"$PUBKEY3\"]" | jq -r '.address')`

We send some coins to it `bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress $P2SH_MULTISIG 1`

Then we generate new blocks to confirm the transaction `bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress 1 "$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress)"`

we create a descriptor with the public keys

```
DESC_NO_CHECKSUM="sh(multi(2,$PUBKEY1,$PUBKEY2,$PUBKEY3))"
DESC_WITH_CHECKSUM=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getdescriptorinfo "$DESC_NO_CHECKSUM" | jq -r '.descriptor')
```

then we import the multisig address

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest importmulti "[{\"desc\": \"$DESC_WITH_CHECKSUM\", \"timestamp\": \"now\", \"internal\": false, \"watchonly\": true}]"
```

then we get the unspent transactions and get the transaction ID, output index (vout), and amount for the UTXO

```
UTXO=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest listunspent | jq -r ".[] | select(.address == \"$P2SH_MULTISIG\")")
TXID=$(echo $UTXO | jq -r '.txid' | tr -d '\n')
VOUT=$(echo $UTXO | jq -r '.vout')
AMOUNT=$(echo $UTXO | jq -r '.amount')
```

then we create a new destination address with the correct change amount

```
DESTADDR=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress)
CHANGE=$(echo "$AMOUNT - 0.0002" | bc | LC_ALL=C awk '{printf "%.8f", $0}')
```

then we create the raw transaction

```
RAW_TX=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest createrawtransaction "[{\"txid\":\"$TXID\",\"vout\":$VOUT}]" "{\"$DESTADDR\":$CHANGE}")
```

we sign it with the private keys of the 2 of 3 addresses

```
PRIVKEY1=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest dumpprivkey $ADDR1)
PRIVKEY2=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest dumpprivkey $ADDR2)

SIGNED_TX=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest signrawtransactionwithkey $RAW_TX "[\"$PRIVKEY1\",\"$PRIVKEY2\"]" "[{\"txid\":\"$TXID\",\"vout\":$VOUT,\"scriptPubKey\":\"$(echo $UTXO | jq -r '.scriptPubKey')\",\"redeemScript\":\"$(bitcoin-cli -regtest createmultisig 2 "[\"$PUBKEY1\",\"$PUBKEY2\",\"$PUBKEY3\"]" | jq -r '.redeemScript')\",\"amount\":$AMOUNT}]")
```

then we can send it

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest sendrawtransaction $(echo $SIGNED_TX | jq -r '.hex')
```

and in the end we generate a new block to confirm the transaction

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress 1 "$(bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress)"
```

Comment: This won't allow you to spend the coins, though, as you need to import the P2SH address into the wallet too. In a legacy wallet, this could be done with `addmultisigaddress`, but in new descriptor wallets all of the above can be done directly with descriptors too.

Comment: I modified my answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I try use `PRIVKEY1=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest dumpprivkey $ADDR1)`, it raises this error: `Only legacy wallets are supported by this command`

Comment: Thats because you were using a descriptor wallet which does not have dumpprivkey, I updated my answer for descriptorwallet

Comment: I'm also getting `Only legacy wallets are supported by this command` for importing address. `bitcoin-cli -regtest importaddress $P2SH_MULTISIG`

Comment: Havent tested my previous solution, they were some mistake I changed the method, be sure to start from the first step.

Comment: You need to use `importdescriptors`, not `importmulti`.

Comment: I have not yet used descriptor wallet :/ gonna have to look into it

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work yet.